# Replace send_keys() for an element found by xpath with javascript exec script python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

This is how I'm currently sending input :

```
          elemnt = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath="//somexpath")
            elemnt.send_keys(tokenId)
```

Is there a way to do it with executing a javascript that will basically type an  input for a given xpath ?
I need this because the website I'm testing has an odd behavior when using send_keys() to type something, when the text is done typing, a loading circle appears and  for some reason it goes to the next page after a search(which should be done by pressing continue)

Manually, I managed to reproduce the issue with  typing a text, the loading circle appears, and if I press enter while the loading circle is still searching it moves to the next page (there is a continue button that does that when it's pressed)

So my thinking here is that send_keys() might have some weird key press that causes the bug to reoccure, and i would like to replace it with some javascript if its possible that types an input for a specific XPath.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this :

```
                                    self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'some value');", self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Introdu TOKEN']"))
```